# How can we rate ourselves as a site as of now?

Tags: discussion

This topic comes up from time to time. I am wonder now that since it has been over a year: How can we rate ourselves as a site now? A current snapshot of Area51 stats is below:

[image: Area 51 stats]

Our number of questions appears to be trending up which is better. Used to be hovering over 1 which was sad. We seem to be lacking in high rep users arguably though we have a fair number but it has not changed much in the last several months. Chat has not been doing well but I don't think that is a metric that matters much in the end.

Are we doing OK? Are we at risk of being shut down at all? I try to ask as many questions as I can but I am losing inspiration. I don't want this place to fail and if there is something we could be doing to step it up a notch I would love to help. Perhaps more ads? Maybe Graphus could ask a question just one time!

Comment: +1 for the Graphus observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no risk of the site getting shut down. StackOverflow used to shut down sites if they did not meet the requirements for graduation, but about a year ago, they officialy [changed that policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/220382). Even if our activity were to drop in half, as long as we are not overrun with spam, the site will remain open.

I'd say we are much closer to graduation than getting shut down, but we are quite a ways away (graduation basically means we get nice artwork for the site, among other perks).  The same post I linked above describes the new requirements for graduation:

> from now on, when a site starts to consistently receive ten new
>   questions every day, we'll consider it for graduation.

So we are a ways away from graduation.  That being said, all of our other statistics are quite healthy.  Our page views have been steadily increasing, with well over 80% coming from search engines.  It'll only be a matter of time before we have 150 users with 200+ reputation.  Overall, I think we're in pretty good shape.

Comment: Thanks for the information.